# Mail header FROM dose'nt work

Tags: php, email

I have a code to send mails, the code work fine and mail sent
but I get the mail from an address wird
the mail that I get the email from: `star1231@a2plcpnl0005.prod.iad2.secureserver.net`

my code:

```
$from = 'From: System@dmworld24.com';
if (!sendMail($_POST['mail'], $text['EMAIL_RECOVER_MSG_SUBJECT'], $text['EMAIL_RECOVER_MSG'], $from))
```

the send mail function:

```
 function sendMail ($to, $subject, $msg, $from, $add = null) {
$from = array($from,
"Reply-To: system@dmworld24.com",
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . PHP_VERSION
 );
 $from = implode("\r\n", $headers);
return mail($to, $subject, $msg, $from);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `From:` from value of variable `$from`

Change from

```
$from = 'From: System@dmworld24.com';
```

Into

```
$from = 'System@dmworld24.com';
```

It is recommended to use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) class.